# How is the cmake install path constructed?

Tags: cmake

If I have a line `install( TARGETS prog DESTINATION foo  )` in my CMakeLists.txt, the target gets installed in `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/foo/prog`, so I figured having
`install( TARGETS prog  )` would put it in `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/prog`. But no, it goes in `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/bin/prog`.

How can I install a target directly in the prefix location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.` as the destination:

```
install(TARGETS prog DESTINATION .)
```

If you don't specify the destination, the default path for executables is used, which is `bin`.